# What are these underlines shown for whitespace at the end of some lines?

Tags: whitespace, markdown-mode, rendering

The following screenshot shows Emacs 26.3 (*GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian*) editing a Markdown file:

[image]

Note that on some lines of the code block, some of the space characters at the end of lines are rendered as `_`. If I go to any of these locations and do a `describe-char`, they are reported as normal spaces:

```
character: SPC (displayed as SPC) (codepoint 32, #o40, #x20)
```

Looking at the file with a hex editor, I can confirm that these are normal `0x20` spaces just like all the other ones that don't show any artefacts.

These artefacts are stable across closing and reopening the file in Emacs. However, they are not shown in `fundamental-mode`, only `markdown-mode`.

What do they mean, do they mean anything or is it just a bug, and is there anything I can do to get rid of them?

Comment: Use `C-u C-x =` to show all the details. If there are any overlays or text properties they will be listed as well. Then you can use their name to figure out what `markdown-mode` is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Markdown, two spaces at the end of the line cause a hard line break. markdown-mode highlights those for you, because otherwise they are indistinguishable from soft line breaks. It seems you have trailing white space in your diagram.

However, this is a bug since it shouldn't apply that face to trailing whitespace inside a code block.